# What are the principles of Leave no Trace?

Tags: leave-no-trace

What are the fundamental principles of leaving no trace in the backcountry?

Comment: This has been needed for a while! Makes a good wiki answer, good work

Comment: I've added this to the [tag for leave no trace](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/tags/leave-no-trace/info). We should likely keep this updated as things progress

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the **[Centre of Outdoor Ethics](https://lnt.org/)**, which runs the most widely accepted ethics program used on private lands for outdoor recreation, there are **seven principles** to leaving no trace:

1. [**Plan Ahead and Prepare**](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-1)
2. [**Travel and Camp on Durable Surfaces**](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-2)
3. [**Dispose of Waste Properly**](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-3)
4. [**Leave What You Find**](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-4)
5. [**Minimize Campfire Impacts**](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-5)
6. [**Respect Wildlife**](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-6)
7. [**Be Considerate of Other Visitors**](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-7)

They are outlined on [their website](https://lnt.org/learn/7-principles) as shown below:

---

## The Leave No Trace Seven Principles

### [1. Plan Ahead and Prepare](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-1)

- Know the regulations and special concerns for the area you'll visit.
- Prepare for extreme weather, hazards, and emergencies.
- Schedule your trip to avoid times of high use.
- Visit in small groups when possible. Consider splitting larger groups into smaller groups.
- Repackage food to minimize waste.
- Use a map and compass to eliminate the use of marking paint, rock cairns or flagging.

### [2. Travel and Camp on Durable Surfaces](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-2)

- Durable surfaces include established trails and campsites, rock, gravel, dry grasses or snow.
- Protect riparian areas by camping at least 200 feet from lakes and streams.
- Good campsites are found, not made. Altering a site is not necessary.

  - In popular areas:

    - Concentrate use on existing trails and campsites.
    - Walk single file in the middle of the trail, even when wet or muddy.
    - Keep campsites small. Focus activity in areas where vegetation is absent.
  - In pristine areas:

    - Disperse use to prevent the creation of campsites and trails.
    - Avoid places where impacts are just beginning.

### [3. Dispose of Waste Properly](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-3)

- Pack it in, pack it out. Inspect your campsite and rest areas for trash or spilled foods. Pack out all trash, leftover food and litter.
- Deposit solid human waste in catholes dug 6 to 8 inches deep, at least 200 feet from water, camp and trails. Cover and disguise the cathole when finished.
- Pack out toilet paper and hygiene products.
- To wash yourself or your dishes, carry water 200 feet away from streams or lakes and use small amounts of biodegradable soap. Scatter strained dishwater.

### [4. Leave What You Find](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-4)

- Preserve the past: examine, but do not touch cultural or historic structures and artifacts.
- Leave rocks, plants and other natural objects as you find them.
- Avoid introducing or transporting non-native species.
- Do not build structures, furniture, or dig trenches.

### [5. Minimize Campfire Impacts](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-5)

- Campfires can cause lasting impacts to the backcountry. Use a lightweight stove for cooking and enjoy a candle lantern for light.
- Where fires are permitted, use established fire rings, fire pans, or mound fires.
- Keep fires small. Only use sticks from the ground that can be broken by hand.
- Burn all wood and coals to ash, put out campfires completely, then scatter cool ashes.

### [6. Respect Wildlife](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-6)

- Observe wildlife from a distance. Do not follow or approach them.
- Never feed animals. Feeding wildlife damages their health, alters natural behaviors, and exposes them to predators and other dangers.
- Protect wildlife and your food by storing rations and trash securely.
- Control pets at all times, or leave them at home.
- Avoid wildlife during sensitive times: mating, nesting, raising young, or winter.

### [7. Be Considerate of Other Visitors](https://lnt.org/learn/principle-7)

- Respect other visitors and protect the quality of their experience.
- Be courteous. Yield to other users on the trail.
- Step to the downhill side of the trail when encountering pack stock.
- Take breaks and camp away from trails and other visitors.
- Let nature's sounds prevail. Avoid loud voices and noises.

---

<sup>(c) Leave No Trace Center for Outdoor Ethics: [www.LNT.org](http://www.LNT.org).</sup>

Comment: I've noticed a lot of resistance to leave no trace.  I think the idea of it is immersed into some peoples minds as a reflection of ideology, therefore, it should not be considered.  I've been interested in how the framework, the fundamental concepts, could be dispersed amongst various communities, such as this, to dispel those ideas....whattever they ultimately are.    Thanks for posting this and answering.  I guess activity like this is how to get ideas in front of more people.

Comment: However revolutionary LNT was a scant 6 years ago, it is now almost universally accepted in principle.