# What is the “Trail User’s Code”?

Tags: hiking, safety, safety-standards

I hear people often talk about the "Trail User’s Code" or read about it and ever wondered what it might be.

Is it some kind of official act?

Comment: This is essentially the Leave No Trace principle - there's plenty of information on the site in regards to this.

Comment: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/what-are-the-principles-of-leave-no-trace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically a unwritten law which can be used to give beginners an overview about the "core rules" while hiking. Due to the fact that it isn't something official, there are many different versions out there. However, it basically always contains this:

> It is important to leave the trail in the same shape you find it. The
>   following Trail User’s Code is a useful guide of conduct on the trail.
>
> - Take nothing but pictures and leave nothing but footprints
> - Hike only along the marked routes
> - Use the stiles; do not climb fences
> - Leave flowers, plants and wildlife for others to enjoy
> - Leave the trail clean; carry out all litter
> - Walk around a farmer's cultivated field, not across it
> - Avoid potential fire hazards by not building fires

Comment: `Walk around a farmer's cultivated field, not across it` is not always true! In the UK some footpaths take you directly through a field, very common where I live - the farmer often salts / limes a field's footpath to prevent growth across it.