# What to do when finding huge pieces of trash?

Tags: europe, litter

When I'm out in the woods I often find huge pieces, like for example a car tire or even something bigger, or huge piles of trash. Of course I can't take that with me on my hike to bring it out.

What should I do then? I feel like this question can't be answered generally so let's narrow it down to Germany or other EU countries. Am I supposed to call the police?

Comment: [This question](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11430/what-should-i-do-about-large-trash-left-by-others-on-usfs-land) might be relevant, as about half the answers were given before the OP clarified that they were interested in U.S. specific advice.

Comment: Now I'm confused: in the linked question OP did comment on what they do in Germany!?

Comment: @cbeleites was just an assumption there

Answer (score 6):

In the UK you'd inform the council. This would be fly tipping and is actually illegal.

> ### [Report fly-tipping or illegal waste dumping](https://www.gov.uk/report-flytipping)
>
> Fly-tipping is the illegal dumping of waste. You can report
>   fly-tipping to the local council.

If it's only a tyre or something small scale they may or may not clean it up. Your probably best getting rid of it yourself. If it's on private land then it's the land owners responsibility. If I own x piece of land I'm well within my rights to leave a tyre on my own land.

If it's in a national park then their is likely laws protecting the natural environment. You can contact the park authority to clarify this. OS maps will tell you if your inside a national park or not.

Comment: Why would it be called fly-tipping?

Comment: It's just the name of it, Uk word for illegal dumping of waste. I think it comes from people driving up, emptying their boots, vans, etc. then driving off.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fly%20tipping

Comment: Is the council akin to city hall?

Comment: I have no idea @Erik?! What's a City Hall! The UK is broken up into [council boroughs](http://www.gazetteer.org.uk/lamap.php) roughly based on historic population size. For example my local council is [Flintshire](http://www.flintshire.gov.uk/). These basically run all local services, like Garbage Collection, Street cleaning, etc. Interestingly in theory these should all contain roughly the same amount of people but they we're drawn up a long time ago so they are no longer equal any more.

Comment: @Liam interesting. A City Hall/Council [like mine](http://www.meridiancity.org/city_council.aspx?id=21295) as you'd expect based on the name is scoped to the city, and their responsibilities sound similar to your council. We also have something scoped more similar to your council called a county, but their responsibilities feel different. Mine is [Ada county](https://adacounty.id.gov/). Thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion for **Germany**: tell the owner.

- The owner often has the strongest interest in having it cleaned up fast, because clean places tend to stay clean, but once some*one* dumped rubbish, others may add to it.
- The owner may know this already but may be waiting e.g. for the weather to be dry enough to haul it out by car/tractor without completely messing up the track.
- The owner can then decide to file a report with the police.

#### How to find the owner?

- Comunal and state owned forest sections may have little signs saying e.g. "city of whereever, forest section nnn, name of section of forest" [Do not confuse with the Waldrettungspunkt (forest rescue point) signs].
- Privately owned forest is more difficult, particularly as the sections can be quite small. The local hunter will usually know who owns which piece. The  police can give you the phone number of the hunter (they do that all the time because of wildlife accidents).